# Convert C#.net object into json using js

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json

I'm trying to convert a C#.net object into json on the client side.
I'm not sure that this is even possible...
I know that the object has been serializable with `BinaryFormatter` class.
Is it possible ? or i'm wasting my time on it.

Comment: What do you mean on the client side? In the browser?

Comment: Json .NET has a serializer, have you tried using that?  What exactly are you trying to do and where are you stuck?  Can you demonstrate what you're attempting?

Comment: It does sound like the wrong approach.  If you tell us more about what you're trying to achieve it would be easier to suggest approaches or alternatives

Comment: I got an object on my server that has been sent with BinaryFormatter.Serialize method and i'm trying to perfom like BinaryFormatter.Deserialize methon on my client side , using javascript.

Comment: If you want to deserialize it inside JavaScript code then the answer is - no you can't

Comment: Ok , is it possible with other language , not js , maybe java ?

Comment: maybe that works for you? https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/178fe024-29f2-467c-a1da-284fedd1ac19

Comment: Nope , i don't need that tool.